# XML to JSON ordered list

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization

Here is a reduced example of an XML object that I am trying to convert to JSON. The key here is that there are a set of child nodes with different properties, some of which repeat, and that need to *stay in order* when they get into JSON. Also, I can't change the XML input format. I don't care, particularly, what format the JSON objects take. I can adapt the later code to whatever I need, as long as the JSON objects are in order when they come out of the conversion, and I can still access the original xml element name (add, stir, move, etc.)

```
<recipe>
   <orderedDirections>
      <add what="flour" to="bowl" amount="1c"/> 
      <add what="sugar" to="bowl" amount="1/2c"/>  
      <stir what="bowl"/>
      <move from="bowl" to="pot" amount="1/2"/>
      <add what="eggs" to="pot"/>
      <stir what="pot"/>
   </orderedDirections>
</recipe>
```

I am currently using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject on the XML to do the conversion, although I am not tied to that particular algorithm. When I do that with default settings, I get:

```
{
  "recipe": {
    "orderedDirections": {
      "add": [
        {
          "@what": "flour",
          "@to": "bowl",
          "@amount": "1c"
        },
        {
          "@what": "sugar",
          "@to": "bowl",
          "@amount": "1/2c"
        },
        {
          "@what": "eggs",
          "@to": "pot"
        }
      ],
      "stir": [
        {
          "@what": "bowl"
        },
        {
          "@what": "pot"
        }
      ],
      "move": {
        "@from": "bowl",
        "@to": "pot",
        "@amount": "1/2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, this is not what I need as the order has gotten completely lost in the process. I think that what I need to do is get a JsonConverter to turn this into something more like this, but I'm not at all sure how to get there:

```
{
  "recipe": {
    "orderedDirections": [
      {
        "@verb": "add",
        "@what": "flour",
        "@to": "bowl",
        "@amount": "1c"
      },
...

      {
        "@verb": "stir",
        "@what": "pot"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is a JsonConverter the right track at all? Is there some property or setting that I can override that would make this happen without me having to be overly specific?

Updated requirements:
These are not the only nodes in the XML document/schema, just the only ones that are giving me trouble. I am currently using:

```
var recipeDoc = XmlDocument.LoadDocument("recipe.xml");
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(recipeDoc);
```

This is producing usable/correct json for all the other 40-50 elements in the XML. I don't mind writing a conversion specification for the orderedDirections node (JsonConverter, XSLT, whatever), but I want to keep the default values for everything else without having to specify it explicitly, including for the child nodes of orderedDirections, which are actually more complicated than I listed in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Most people don't want a vanilla XML-to-JSON conversion, they want a custom conversion from a specific XML form to a specific JSON form, and for that you need to be able to write detailed rules. XSLT 3.0 provides a suitable template engine:

```
<xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:map>
    <xsl:map-entry key="recipe">
      <xsl:map>
        <xsl:map-entry key="orderedDirections">
          <xsl:array>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//orderedDirections/*"/>
          </xsl:array>
        </xsl:map-entry>
      </xsl:map>
    </xsl:map-entry>
  </xsl:map>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="orderedDirections/*">
  <xsl:map>
    <xsl:map-entry key="'@verb'" select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  </xsl:map>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="orderedDirections/*/@*">
  <xsl:map-entry key="'@'||local-name()" select="string(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

(The `xsl:array` instruction is an embarrassing omission from the XSLT 3.0 specification, but you'll find it in Saxon [disclaimer: my product], and there are workarounds if you want to stick within the standard).

Comment: Is it possible to define the XSLT for just the orderedDirections element? That element is just one in a much larger XML document, and the only one that is coming in incorrectly in the vanilla conversion that I am using. I don't want to have to define an XSLT for the whole thing.

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult to set up generic template rules that reproduce the "vanilla" behaviour. But I don't know what the "vanilla" behaviour is, e.g. what your converter does with XML Namespaces. There are a lot of converters around and they all tackle these problems in different ways.

Comment: I've updated my original question. I don't know exactly what all the vanilla rules are either, and I'd really rather not reinvent the wheel for this.